# Calculating integral on area

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to calculate integral $$\int_L{x^2-y^2\rm d}s\,{\rm}$$ where $L$ is the contour of parallelogram, where $A=(1,1), B=(2,1), C=(3,3), D=(2,3)$

Comment: So, show us your work and where you got stuck.

Comment: A good start would be to draw the parallelogram to understand the domain of integration

Comment: And I need to go make some dinner. Oh, you wanted some help? Then show us what you have tried and explain where and why you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

After drawing the parallelogram you can see that $y$ depends differently of $x$ when $x\in(1,2)$ and when  $x\in(2,3)$ :
$$\int_L{x^2-y^2\rm d}s\,{\rm}=\int_{x=1}^2\int_{y=1}^{x+1}x^2-y^2dydx+\int_{x=2}^3\int_{y=1+x-2}^{2}x^2-y^2dydx\\=\int_{x=1}^2\int_{y=1}^{x+1}x^2-y^2dydx+\int_{x=2}^3\int_{y=x-1}^{2}x^2-y^2dydx$$
Can you finish ?

Comment: Oops I took away the nice 7777 rep count... sorry ;)

Comment: argh 1111 rep to go ;)

Comment: +1..Just trying to help you get to your next mononomial target :)